# Run logic when reactive repository returns result and also when empty?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I need to run a different set of logic when the reactive repo returns a result and when it is empty.

```java
return usrRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail()).flatMap(dbUser -> {
    // Execute logic when mono is not empty
    return ServerResponse.noContent().build();
}).switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> 
    // Execute logic when Mono is empty
    return ServerResponse.noContent().build();
});
```

Here, Not able to return `ServerResponse.noContent().build()` when Mono is not empty.

And it always executes logic inside `switchifempty` even the mono is not empty.

Comment: With the code provided I don't see how it could always execute the `switchIfEmpty()` logic unless your `flatMap()` call was returning an empty publisher somehow. A [mcve] would be best here, but otherwise can you put a `.log()` after each step in your reactive chain and paste the result here? That may help us work out what's going on.

Comment: I've VTC as requiring more details since there's not enough here, but will happily take a look if more details are provided.